# Does this change improve my design with regards to the Law Of Demeter?

Tags: java, law-of-demeter

Let's say I need write a Wrapper for a 3rd party class which I'm not able to change.

The interface of the class looks like this

```
class Rewriter {
    public List<Mapping> getMappings();
}
```

The wrapper looks like this

```
class RewriterSpec {
    private final Rewriter rewriter;

    public RewriterSpec(Rewriter rewriter) {
        this.rewriter = rewriter;
    }

    public addMapping(Mapping m) {
        rewriter.getMappings().add(m);
    }
}
```

So from my understanding the `RewriterSpec` violates the Law of Demeter because it requires structural knowledge about the Rewriter.

Now, the question is, would it be better from a design / testing point of view to just pass in the list of mappings?

```
class Rewriter {
    public List<Mapping> getMappings();
}
```

The wrapper looks like this

```
class RewriterSpec {
    private final Rewriter rewriter;

    public RewriterSpec(List<Mapping> mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public addMapping(Mapping m) {
        mappings.add(m);
    }
}
```

Is it okay to just pass the List by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia states the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

> More formally, the Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method m of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of objects:[2]
>
> - O itself
> - m's parameters
> - Any objects created/instantiated within m
> - O's direct component objects
> - A global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of m

By following these principals, you could define a method in the Rewriter interface to directly add Mapping objects to its list to satisfy the principle (A global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of m).

```
class RewriterSpec {
    private final Rewriter rewriter;

    public RewriterSpec(Rewriter rewriter) {
        this.rewriter = rewriter;
    }

    public addMapping(Mapping m) {
        rewriter.addMapping(m);
    }
}
```

Considering Rewriter can't be modified, you can opt for the following:

```
class RewriterSpec {
    private final Rewriter rewriter;
    private final List<Mapping> mappings;

    public RewriterSpec(Rewriter rewriter) {
        this.rewriter = rewriter;
        this.mappings = rewriter.getMappings();
    }

    public addMapping(Mapping m) {
        mappings.addMapping(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @luc14n0 in general this is good advice but sadly I'm not able to change the Rewriter interface.

Comment: Consider that `Rewriter` class is not modifiable.

Comment: Perhaps you can extend the constructor of RewriterSpec to also assign a reference to the map in Rewriter.